# How to avoid outside of request scope exception in silex application?

Tags: php, request, silex

After restructuring my silex1.2 application, I am now getting hit by:

> exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Accessed request service
>   outside of request scope. Try moving that call to a before handler or
>   controller.' in
>   ../vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php:150

I used to setup the appilcation's config this way:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app->register(new ConfigServiceProvider($configFile));
$fileFinder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
foreach ($fileFinder->in($configPath . 'country') as $file) {
   /* @var SplFileInfo $file */
    $app->register(new ConfigServiceProvider($file->getRealPath()));
}
```

I now wanted to replace the `foreach` loop by injecting a specific value which I get from the user's request. So I wanted to access `$request->query->get('country')`; yet I cannot since `app['request']` is out of scope at that point.

I don't understand the error message, as in:

- When and why are request objects out of scope in silex?
- How am I supposed to move the call before handler and controllers when it is the very first thing I do on setting up my application?

Basically, I want to access request data early on on in order to get one value. How can I achieve that in order to bootstrap application accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to use `Request` before it is initialized, before `$app->run()`.
You can manually initialize `Request`:

```
$app = new \Silex\Application();
$app['request'] = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
.....
$app->run($app['request']);
```

or make lazy loading in service providers:

```
$app['object1'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new Object1($app['request']->query->get('country'));
});
...
```

and somewhere in controller get these variable as `$app['object1']`

Comment: The scary part is that my current debug session just had me arrive at the same conclusion and I was about to write the same thing. :D

Comment: There seems to be something off. `Request::createFromGlobals` creates an request object, yet it has no GET parameters.

Comment: Do you mean parameters from route? If so, they are set in `$app->run()` on `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event. Try to use `$app->share(..)` for defining proper objects in service provider. Or describe how do you use `$request->query->get('country')` in service provider initialization.

Comment: I think it has to do with my architecture and how the functional test sets up the silex application. The functional test has no request at when it build the app, yet it does when requesing the application "the normal way". In the functional test, the request are fired after the app has already been build implicitly assuming the request is not needed at bootstrap level.